# Is there an easier way to find a certain format within a longer String?

Tags: java, string

I'm building a program and ran into a problem, I'm not sure how to conquer it most efficiently.

I need to write an algorithm that takes a String in this format:

> 12/05/2014 PROJ Assignment 4      20/20 100 4

and it will remove everything but

> 20/20

so I can then substring that and parse it to an integer value. This is what I've tried, but I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be. My while loop works, going from each / to the next, but the loop will only stop when the string has 20 100 4 left, I need the 20/20, but not the 100 or 4.

```
String line = "12/05/2014 PROJ Assignment 4      20/20 100 4";
int slashIndex = line.indexOf("/");
String temp = line.substring((slashIndex+1));

System.out.println(temp);

while(temp.indexOf("/") != -1){
    slashIndex = temp.indexOf("/");
    temp = temp.substring((slashIndex+1));
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

If I do it the way I'm doing, I could potentially use the slashIndex of the last slash, and then make a substring from the original String- however the score may vary. It could be 20/20 or it could be 100/200, or 10/100, so how could I make the program dynamic enough to decide where to cut it up?

Any thoughts or ideas would be great, thanks.

- Connor

Comment: You could use regex. It looks like you're always looking for some decimals, a slash, and some more decimals, with whitespace on each side. I don't remember the special characters for those, but I think a regular expression could do it quite easily.

Comment: Is the format always the same? Strings separated by spaces and you are interested in the `5th` string?

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll google regex now. The format will always be the same, ###/###, but it could be ##/### or ##/## or #/## or #/#. It's a score on a test or a paper etc. the String comes from a website that we use to see our grades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) the input on one or more whitespaces (`\\s+`). The 5th field will have index `4` of the parts.

```
String t = "12/05/2014 PROJ Assignment 4 20/20 100 4";
String[] parts = t.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(parts[4]);
```

Output:

```
20/20
```

Comment: Little nitpick perhaps `\\s+` taking in consideration his example perhaps is a stream of spaces.

Comment: OK, why not? Changed.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    str = str.replaceAll(".* (\\d+/\\d+) .*", "$1");
```

Comment: Since the OP has no regexp experience, a litte explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = "12/05/2014 PROJ Assignment 4 20/20 100 4"
String pattern = " ([0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,3}) ";
String numbers = line.replaceAll(pattern, "$1");
System.out.println(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with regex, this one, ensure that you got exacly the same input format string.

[I create an regexplain for an "explication of the regex"](http://tinyurl.com/n5gfjfp)

```
Pattern mypat = Pattern.compile("\d{2}\\/\d{2}\\/\d{4} [A-Z]{4} \w+ \d? (\d+\/\d+) \d+ \d?");
// ...
Matcher m = mypat.matcher("12/05/2014 PROJ Assignment 4 20/20 100 4");
if (m.matches()) {
  String value   = m.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a regex (you may find something more sophisticated regarding the actual regex, i am not a regex expert) that matches the string you want, for example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([2][0]\\/[2][0])");
```

then create a matcher using the pattern

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("12/05/2014 PROJ Assignment 4 20/20 100 4");
```

and finally if `m.matches()` get the first group that matched:

```
m.group(0)
```

Comment: This will *only* match `20/20`. What about `10/30`?

Comment: What about `200/350`. What about `10/100`

Comment: You may edit the regex according to your needs for example: [0-9]{2}